# Indexing a context list in template

Tags: django

In my view, I pass a context to a template, which contains a two-dimensional list of (x, y) coordinates:

```
_points = [[100, 100], [200, 200], [300, 200]]
context = {'points': _points}
return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

In my template, I want to draw a line between each of these points:

```
var c = document.getElementById("graph"); // "graph" is a canvas element
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
// Move to the first point
ctx.moveTo({{ points[0][0] }}, {{ points[0][1] }});
// Loop through all points and draw connecting line
{% for point in points %}
    ctx.lineTo({{ point[0] }}, {{ point[1] }});
{% endfor %}
ctx.stroke();
```

However, I get an error on the line:

```
ctx.lineTo({{ point[0] }}, {{ point[1] }});
```

saying `Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'point[0]'`.

What's the correct way to be indexing list variables from the context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could unpack this list in-place, like this:

```
{% for x, y in points %}
    ctx.lineTo({{ x }}, {{ y }});
{% endfor %}
```

(See the [Django documentation for `for`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#for))

If you want to get them out "longhand", you should be able to write `{{ point.0 }}` - though I agree it's weird that the single index doesn't work correctly.